# Which language should I learn for a trip to Bali?

Tags: languages, indonesia, bali

I plan to travel to Bali and want to learn some basic words in native language, like "Hello", "Thank you", ....

But I'm not sure which language is native to Bali. It looks like there are Indonesian (Malay) and multiple forms of Balinese language.

Which one should I choose?

Comment: Are you just going to be in tourist areas? It sounds like you don't want to try to learn the language but just a few words. If you really want so few words why not learn "hello" and "thank you" in both Indonesian and Balinese?

Comment: It's unclear when to use what. And even worse I have found that "The members of the four castes use different dialects of the Balinese language" :(

Comment: WikiVoyage has both an [Indonesian phrasebook](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Indonesian_phrasebook) and a [Balinese phrasebook](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Balinese_phrasebook), but the former is much more fully fleshed out while the latter has lots of gaps.

Comment: Haven't been there myself, but my understanding is that lots of monolingual Aussies go to Bali.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The native language in Bali is bahasa Bali (Balinese). The official language in Indonesia is bahasa Indonesia (not Malay as you said, due to political reasons the two languages have separated). Anyway, Bahasa Indonesia is used by all people for education, government and almost everything else in Indonesia. You definitely should choose Bahasa Indonesia since it is spoken by all people in Bali and all other islands of Indonesia. Also, people in the touristic places will be able to understand basic English words and you can manage by English only, but it will be nicer if you use some Bahasa Indonesia words and people there will respect that.

Here are some few words that can help you get by:

- **Yes:** Ya
- **No:** Tidak or Nggak
- **Hello:** Halo or Salam
- **How are you:** Apa kabar
- **Fine:** Baik
- **Please:** Tolong
- **Excuse me:** Permisi
- **Sorry:** Maaf
- **Thank you:** Terima kasih
- **You are welcome:** Sama sama
- **How much:** Berapa
- **Where:** Dimana
- **What:** Apa
- **When:** Kapan
- **Restaurant:** Restoran
- **Toilet:** Kamar mandi or just use toilet
- **Room:** Kamar
- **Food:** Makanan
- **Hospital:** Rumah sakit
- **Airport:** Bandara
- **Beach:** Pantai
- **Expensive:** Mahal
- **Me, I:** Saya or Aku
- **I want:** Saya mau

Remember, the letter **C** in Indonesian is pronounced as **CH**.

P.S. I speak Bahasa Indonesia and I always managed by just Bahasa Indonesia anywhere in Indonesia.

Comment: The **c** hint is good; but I notice none of your suggsted phrases use that letter :)

Comment: @Flimzy lol you are right :) I just added this info in case the OP wants to read something there.

Comment: a bit of correction : Malay and Indonesian language is not separated because of political. they come from same root, however after Indonesia has EYD ( Ejaan Yang Disempurnakan - "Perfected Pronouncation" ) Indonesian language develop to a different way by adopting English, Indian, Arab and Dutch language. However Indonesian still able to understand most of Malay words.

Comment: @RudyGunawan they became separated for political reasons, then developed individually from there. Though at the time there probably were already enough differences to classify bahasa Indonesia as a separate dialect at least, a regional language based on Malay quite possibly.

Comment: @RudyGunawan They are separated for political reasons, read this part in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_language#Official_status

Comment: The wiki actually said : This has been based more upon political nuance and the "history of its standardization". So I guess you are right in some aspect - However as an Indonesian, I do feel standardization is the bigger factor here.

Comment: Free English lesson (-; [Do native English speakers use the word “touristic”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40682)

Comment: Both Standard Malay and Standard Indonesian are artificial standard languages, a bit like Standard High German or [MSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Standard_Arabic). English is unusual in not having an artificial standard language. Norwegian is special in having two to choose from! Standardized languages are usually based on the dialect of the capital city or some place with greatest "prestige" or on principles of "language purity". Normally most people will natively speak a related natural local dialect and use the standard as a lingua franca to talk to everybody else.

Comment: **Temple**: Candi -- pronounced "chandi".  There are _lots_ of temples in Bali.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

Since Bali's main income is from tourism, you can survive by just using English, and the local people are able to speak English or at least "broken English" (This is not applicable to any other island in Indonesia).

If you want to use local language, you better choose to learn a bit of Indonesian words. Some basic words (other than what MeNoTalk has mentioned) can be found below :

- YES : Ya
- No  : Bukan / Tidak (formal) Enggak (informal)
- Police : Polisi
- Eat : Makan
- Food : Makanan ( Makan with postfix -an )
- Drink : Minum
- Sleep : Tidur
- Cheap : murah
- Help  : Tolong
- Medicine : Obat
- Country : Negara
- Name : Nama

Comment: Depending on where you go it's true for all islands... There's areas of Bali as remote as a mountain village on Flores or Lombok, and few would speak English there (though probably some, especially with eco-tourism becoming more important and opening those more remote areas to foreign travelers).